# issues with C++ executable

Tags: c++, validation

I have a C++ generated executable in Solaris 8.  The problem I have is that this executable uses a command line parameter to run.

For example:

```
$ myprog 123412341234AB
```

This is a valid 14 digit hexdecimal value.  However, if for some reason there are symbols like `^ > < >> << &` etc., then the program does not behave properly per se.  I am not talking core dumps per se but
for example one of the checks I do is via isxdigit.  Apparently it is not good enough to catch
something like `1234123412341^` or `12341234(12341`, so I am just trying to see if I can detect all these symbols in an effort to just exit properly.  I mean, some of these symbols have special meaning in Unix and I guess that is why the program does not understand how to handle it.

Do you have any thoughts on how to address this?  Do I just try to find all these symbols and the moment I detect them in the command, I just exit out with an error message?
How would I go about doing this?

I am using `std::string`.  So maybe a list like `!@#$%^&*()<><<>>` etc., where I can detect and get out.  I am not sure if there is an easier way to do this so Unix does not think I am giving it a system command when in fact it is just an input to a program, albeit it just happens to be a wrong/invalid input.

Comment: Note that `myprog 123412341234AB > foo.txt 2>&1` will give you one command-line argument, the `123412341234AB`.  However, its standard output and standard error streams will go into the file `foo.txt`.  It's not that the program doesn't understand how to handle those, it's that the program can't possibly handle them, since it never sees the extra characters.

Comment: Please define "does not behave properly" as it will effect the correctness and usefulness of the answers below. Also, are you using escaping to pass those special characters in the arguments?

Comment: my input needs to be a 14 digit hexadecimal input. i am not expect these symbolic chars but what if there are numbers that actually have those...i need a way to detect and handle those cases. atm i am not able to and if i am processing like 300k of these numbers i will be in trouble if it just fails on those cases. i guess that is what i was trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fix this by modifying your program -- those special characters are being
interpreted by the shell before your code ever sees them.

You can prevent this by single-quoting the command-line argument:

```
myprog 'some_string_<with_special&>!chars'
```

or by escaping the special characters (by preceding each one with a backslash):

```
myprog some_string_\<with_special\&\>\!chars
```

Comment: yea i think the onus of responsibility to call my executable should be on their head not mine. THey should call it like that so the shell can differentiate. I should only be responsible once the value is passed into my program. For that I think the isxdigit function works fine. checking the size and almos making sure the string is not empty are just some of the checks i do. So i think that would take care of it. don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just to address one part of the question, you could make a "isxstring" function like this:

```
bool isxstring(const std::string &s) {
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
        if(!isxdigit(*it)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you aren't doing something at least similar to this, then you aren't properly checking if every character is a hex-digit.

This would also likely be a valid definition:

```
bool isxstring(const std::string &s) {
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF") == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These characters are special to the command shell, and are being stripped off before your program even starts. Read up on quoting or escaping special characters for your shell.

Comment: I do wonder if he is escaping the characters to get them passed to the program since he doesn't say.

Comment: i am not doing any escaping of any of those chars. I did not really anticipate this issue till now. I was happy with just checking the length/size/making sure the string is not empty and using isxdigit function. this was something i just happened to find and not sure what to do about it. i expect the third party will be just calling this exe and using the value i return in another program. but i just wanted to see if there was anything i could do in terms of error handling per say since they will not have access to source only exe.